# How to load images faster from Google drive or an alternative

Tags: flutter, dart

I made an app that shows places, now all my images are on Google drive. I'm references the image by url, it works but it's very slow compared to referencing the image from Google itself (I have tried it a lot of images that I have are not on google so I use Google drive).

I don't want to save all the images in the app because I have more than 300 images.

This is I sample of my database:

```
Place(
      id: "p1",
      title: "test",
      imageUrl:
          "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1H2RtfQh9_iu86On_hETb-jXDSPgrsJSw",
),
Place(
      id: "p2",
      title: "test2",
      imageUrl:
          "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1_hP1QIxpTybals6ppqfBs45DDb14b2Mm",
```

Is there a way to make the loading time faster or a different way/host to use to get a better load times?

If I do the same thing just use a link from Google, the loading time is a lot faster